# Search inside the name column of a MYSQL and NODE JS database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I need help to know why my code doesn't work. I want to search a column within an MYSQL and NODE JS database by the name attribute, it seems like I'm doing it wrong, but by id, it finds the data that I pass...

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-snyder-k1tr9b?file=/routes/products.routes.js

```
router.get('/search-name/:name', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.params.name
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE ?`, [name], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(rows)
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: Share an example of the name you are passing in, and the string you hope to match

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct in case you put the correct name of the product
[image: search-full-name]

In case you want to use operator `LIKE` you should put it between `%` or `_`, according to [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

> There are two wildcards often used in conjunction with the LIKE
> operator:
>
> - The percent sign (%) represents zero, one, or multiple characters
> - The underscore sign (_) represents one, single character
>   Blockquote

You should put it in the single quote and `%` operator like this, it will allow you to filter the name of product by few characters:

```js
router.get("/search-name/:name", (req, res) => {
  let name = req.params.name;
  connection.query(
    `SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%${name}%'`,
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

And here is the result:
[image: result]